# How to print out more than one Pair of prime numbers

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, compilation, primes

This is a part of a code which only prints out one pair of prime number **(1 3)**. How do I print out all pairs until 10000? **(1 3) (5 7)...until 10000**

```
    int paarPrim = -1;
for(int max = 2; max < 10000; max++) {
    if(isPrim(max)) {
        if(max - paarPrim <= 2) {
            printf("(%i %i)", paarPrim, max);
        }
            paarPrim = 1;

    }
}
```

Comment: 1 is not prime.

Comment: What's a pair of primes? Aren't (3 5) a pair?

Comment: If you want to output all primes in groups of two, you could just output the primes as they are detected and then think about logic to have parenthesis output in the right places. - To control that, one state variable, `bool inPair`, should do.

Comment: I think something like (3,5) (5,7) (11,13) (17,19) would be a valid output. So actually a pair of primes with a difference of 2

Answer (score 1):

```
#include "stdio.h"

int is_prime(int num)
{
    if (num <= 1) return 0;
    if (num % 2 == 0 && num > 2) return 0;
    for (int i = 3; i < num / 2; i += 2)
    {
        if (num % i == 0)
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}




int main()

{

int prim_arry[10000];
int p = 0;

for (int max = 2; max < 10000; max++) 
{
    if (is_prime(max)) 
    {

        prim_arry[p++] =max;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < p; i+=2)
{
    if (i == p - 1)
    {
        printf("(%d)", prim_arry[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("(%d,%d)", prim_arry[i], prim_arry[i + 1]);
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems what you need is something like the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

int is_prime( unsigned long long int n )
{
    int prime = n % 2 == 0 ? n == 2 : n != 1;

    for ( unsigned long long int i = 3; prime && i <= n / i; i+= 2 )
    {
        prime = n % i != 0;
    }

    return prime;
}

int main(void) 
{
    const unsigned int UPPER_VALUE = 1000;

    for ( unsigned int i = 2, prev = 0, first = 0; i < UPPER_VALUE; i++ )
    {
        if ( is_prime( i ) )
        {
            if ( first ^= 1 )
            {
                prev = i;
            }
            else if ( i - prev <= 2 )
            {
                printf( "(%u, %u) ", prev, i );
            }
            else
            {
                first = 1;
                prev = i;
            }
        }
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
(2, 3) (5, 7) (11, 13) (17, 19) (29, 31) (41, 43) (59, 61) (71, 73) (101, 103) 
(107, 109) (137, 139) (149, 151) (179, 181) (191, 193) (197, 199) (227, 229) 
(239, 241) (269, 271) (281, 283) (311, 313) (347, 349) (419, 421) (431, 433) 
(461, 463) (521, 523) (569, 571) (599, 601) (617, 619) (641, 643) (659, 661) 
(809, 811) (821, 823) (827, 829) (857, 859) (881, 883)
```

In the program I used the constant `UPPER_VALUE` equal to `1000` instead of `10000` to restrict the output.:) Of course you may use the constant equal to `10000` or to any other value.

Also you can optimize the loop moving the output of the first pair `(2, 3)` outside the loop and defining the loop itself like

```
    for ( unsigned int i = 5, prev = 0, first = 0; i < UPPER_VALUE; i += 2 )
```